# rails: proper replacement of deeply nested if-else conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, nested

What would be the best way in **ruby** to find out the first time when a function F turns out to be true on the set of values A1, A2, A3, ...? If none of them turns F into **true**, then **nil** is returned.

In details: suppose that

```
F(A1)=false, F(A2)=false,  F(A3)=true, ...
```

What I need is that A3 is returned and procedure quits without applying function F to the remaining values A4, A5, ...

One could do this with the help of the nested **if-else** conditions but for long list of values A1, A2, ... it seems too tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage `Enumerable#detect` to return the first entry in a collection that is true.

Something like:

```
def check(arg)
  arg == true
end

result = [false, true, true].detect do |n|
  puts "checking: #{n}"
  check(n)
end
```

You'll see that with that input of `[false, true, true]` it yields:

```
checking: false
checking: true
```

So it stops running after the 2nd iteration which returns true.

Comment: I think it is exactly what I need. I had not known this function.

Comment: Keep in mind that `detect` also *returns* the object for which the first value returns true.  So `[obj1, obj2, obj3].detect{|o| o.id == 5}` will return obj2 if it's `id` is `5` (and `obj1`'s is not)

Answer (score 2):

If the values are in a list, you could use the [`Enumerable#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) function:

```
my_stuff.detect { |item| F(item) }
```

Edit:  I originally suggested `map` and `any?`, but the other answer of `Enumerable#detect` seems best.  Changed example code to reflect that.